# Gradient descent - contour map

Tags: gradient-descent

Given a 1024x918 matrix i drew a contour map and marked 8 points on it (top of the mountains). Using gradient descent I want to find shortest way down given the only matrix. How should I approximate the value of the gradient and what grid point should I pick?

[image]

Comment: Where the contours are closest together marks the point where the gradient is steepest. It's not clear how you used the matrix to draw the contour map.

Comment: I used contour matlab function. But how do I find the closest point on the next contour?